# null в запросе к бд при использовании flask-whooshee

Tags: python, flask, flask-sqlalchemy

Использую flask-whooshee. Получаю такое сообщение:

> /home/dmitry/projects/tut9/venv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/sqlalchemy/sql/elements.py:3779: SAWarning: Textual SQL expression 'null' should be explicitly declared as text('null') (this warning may be suppressed after 10 occurrences)
>   {"expr": util.ellipses_string(element)})

views.py:

```
res = Items.query.whooshee_search('panel').all()
```

models.py:

```
@whooshee.register_model('title', 'body')
class Items(db.Model):
tablename = 'items'
bind_key = 'items'

id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key = True)
title = db.Column(db.Unicode)
body = db.Column(db.Text)
```

init.py:

```
app.register_blueprint(bla1)
app.register_blueprint(bla2)
app.register_blueprint(bla3)

from app.database import db, bcrypt, whooshee
whooshee.init_app(app)
```

database.py:

```
from flask.ext.sqlalchemy import SQLAlchemy
from flask.ext.bcrypt import Bcrypt
from flask.ext.whooshee import Whooshee

db = SQLAlchemy()
bcrypt = Bcrypt()
whooshee = Whooshee()
```

Не могу понять, почему запрос null???